# I have recorded a macro, now i want it to loop throw all worksheets and not write the code 30 times, can someone help me

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Test()
'
' Test Macro
'

'
    Sheets("test").Select
    Columns("A:D").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("test").Select
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("test").Select
    Columns("J:K").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("test").Select
    Columns("O:O").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("J1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Rows("1:4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Product_Id"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Category"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Brand"
    Range("D1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Model"
    Range("E1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "EAN"
    Range("F1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "UPC"
    Range("G1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SKU"
    Range("H1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Supplier_Shop_Price"
    Range("I1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "In_Voice"
    Range("J1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "In_Stock"
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: [so] is not a free coding service. What is the problem you're having doing this?

Comment: Hi Patrik, please take a while and look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just simple loop: You can do it for example like this:

```
Sub RUN()
For Each wk In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
wk.Activate
    Test
Next wk
End Sub
```

add :

```
Set wk = ActiveSheet
```

in the begining on Test Macro

and use wk instead of Sheets("Sheet1")
for example 
instead of

```
Sheets("test").Select Columns("A:D").Select
```

this

```
wk.Select Columns("A:D").Select
```

Please fix formating in this question.

Comment: Just to add use `Dim wk as worksheet` at the beginning of this. and @Patrik get explicitly state your ranges instead of using `.select` It will speed up your code so much more. This can generally be done for example by replacing the select and selection and making it one line so `Columns("A:D").Select / Selection.Copy` becomes `Columns("A:D").copy`